# Seaborn jointplot: fixing bin range in marginals

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to fix the bin range for both the x- and y- marginal distributions on a hexbin plot, because I want to overlay the marginals with a plot of another distribution.

I can set the number of bins using

```
g=sns.jointplot(x='age',y='value',data=joint_data, space=0, color='g', kind='hex',
                stat_func = None, marginal_kws=dict(bins=num_bins))
```

and I can set the specific bins along both axes using

```
g=sns.jointplot(x='age',y='value',data=joint_data, space=0, color='g', kind='hex',
                stat_func = None, marginal_kws=dict(bins=numpy.linspace(x_min, x_max,100))
```

but I want to define different ranges for the axes separately. There doesn't appear to be a marginal_kws for the axes individually.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how the resulting plot does not meet your expectations. It would also help if you could provide a mockup of the desired result

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the two marginal axes separately, you need to use a `JointGrid` directly, instead of the more user-friendly `jointplot()`.

Have a look at [seaborn's JointGrid documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid). In particular the example titled "Draw the two marginal plots separately:" is the most relevant. Basically, you get a reference to the marginal axes using `g.ax_marg_x` and `g.ax_marg_y` and then you can use any plotting function you want on these axes

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="m", edgecolor="white")
_ = g.ax_marg_x.hist(tips["total_bill"], color="b", alpha=.6,
                      bins=np.arange(0, 60, 5))
_ = g.ax_marg_y.hist(tips["tip"], color="r", alpha=.6,
                      orientation="horizontal",
                      bins=np.arange(0, 12, 1))
```